# Android BLE CallBacks, OnRead/OnWrite Super

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been working with Android BLE classes for 5 or 6 month, i've quite understood how everything works.
Today I noticed that in the BluetoothGatt Callback methods are included super methods like  `super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);`

My question now is, what do they do? I've never noticed any difference between working with them or without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call the parent methods since they do nothing.
Where exactly have you seen this?

Comment: @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
           //My code
        }

Comment: So you have seen it only in your code? Why did you write that in the first place? Just remove super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);